# jQuery UI Dialog: $(".modal").dialog is not a function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

On my page, I am loading some HTML (via AJAX) into a div. The new HTML contains my `$('.modal')` jQuery UI Dialog. Once the HTML is loaded, FireBug gives me an error message for each modal in my HTML saying:

```
$(".modal").dialog is not a function
    height: 'auto'
```

The weird thing is that it's working. When I click the element that triggers the modal to appear, it appears! What should I do to prevent these messages from showing?

Comment: restart firefox, does it still happen, what about ie / chrome? Remember firebug is buggy - always restart firefox & check the other browsers if it seems odd

Answer (score 3):

put this in your document

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do you know OP has not already added these files to his document?

Comment: if those libraries are included, I believe that OP is enough intelligent to not include them again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you load jquery before jquery-ui in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to call $(".modal").dialog after the ajax has finished loading

Answer (score -1):

hmm

```
var dialog = $(".modal").dialog({ autoOpen: false });


$("#click").click( function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

this one works for me fine !